# a connected graph $G=(V,E)$ such that $i(G)> ((3/4)V)-2$

Tags: graph-theory

Dominating set for a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a subset $D$ of $V$ such that every vertex not in $D$ is adjacent to at least one member of $D$. The domination number $γ(G)$ is the number of vertices in a smallest dominating set for $G$.

Independent set is also a dominating set if and only if it is a maximal independent set, so any maximal independent set in a graph is necessarily also a minimal dominating set. Thus, the smallest maximal independent set is greater in size than the smallest independent dominating set. The independent domination number $i(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the size of the smallest independent dominating set (or, equivalently, the size of the smallest maximal independent set).

i need a connected graph $G=(V,E)$ such that $i(G)> ((3/4)V)-2$ or $i(G) > ((2/3)V)-1$.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

$P_4$, the path on 4 vertices fulfills your condition. We have $i(P_4)=2$ which is bigger than both $4\frac34-2=1$ and $4\frac23-1=\frac43$